# Codeigniter 3: foreach inside form_input

Tags: forms, codeigniter, input, foreach

I'm just starting with CodeIgniter and I can't output the value of my form_input. Here's my code:

```
<?= form_input('gender','','type="text" class="form-control form-input" value="'.foreach($profile as $prof){echo $prof->gender;}.'" disabled id="name" style="cursor:default"');?>
```

is my syntax even correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your syntax is not correct. Your arguments to `form_input` are wacky and, as you have it, only one input field is created. The "value" of that input might be something like

```
value='malefemalefemalemalemalemalsemalefemale',
```

Pretty sure that's not what you want.

Actually, from the code you post it's hard to know what you do want. My guess is this

```
<?php
//create an array with attribute values that don't change
$attributes = [
    'class' => "form-control form-input",
    'style' => "cursor:default",
];

//create a counter
$i = 0;

foreach($profile as $prof)
{   
    //inputs need a unique "name" and "id", use the counter for that purpose
    $attributes['name'] = 'gender'.$i;
    $attributes['id'] = "name".$i;
    //add the 'value' of each profile to the array     
    $attributes['value'] = $prof->gender;
    //send the array to form_input
    echo form_input($attributes, NULL, 'disabled');
    echo "<br>"; //new line
    $i++; //increase value of counter by one for next loop run
}
```

The above will output a text field (each on a separate line) for each profile.

Documentation on [`form_input'](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_input#form_input).

The "name" of the inputs will be "gender0", "gender1", etc, which will work. That is not the only way to do it. You could also use input arrays. That syntax is `name='gender[]'`. Either approach will work for the "name" but it won't work for the "id" attributes which must be unique.